Inserting/Updating delta lake without changes increases data size
I created a dataflow that inserts or updates a data lake (ADLS Gen2) from a SQL Server table, essentially mirroring the table. Every time I run the dataflow, it creates a new parquet file that's about the same size as the file created from the initial copy, even if nothing has changed in the source table. I've queried the delta lake using a SQL endpoint to verify that the dataflow isn't changing the (SQL view of the) data, but clearly the number of files (and space used) is growing. Is Azure Data Factory or its delta interface not smart enough to detect that the data hasn't changed and simply log a "no-op" for the purpose of time travel queries? Is it possible to better control file/space growth? 'Auto compact' and 'Optimized write' are enabled on the sink.
 


After overwriting the table you can run VACUUM with low retention to keep a limited number of parquet files. About "detecting that the data hasn't changed and simply log a "no-op"", that would require a full table comparison which is more expensive than simply overwriting the table.
